# eclipse tomcat server add/remove alias?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I'm trying to use the Eclipse server view to deploy an app to tomcat.  This works, but its deploying to a different directory than I'd prefer.

For example, my project is named abc.application.finance so eclipse is deploying to webapps/abc.application.finance, but I really want it deployed to webapps/FINANCE.

I need something like an alias for the project name, but I don't see any where in the server view add/remove feature to specify this.

Where do I need to to make a change so I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
tomcat->module->edit
then edit path of your application